# How to mitigate Log4j Security Vulnerability (CVE-2021-45105) without upgrading

Tags: java, security, log4j

This question is specifically for most recent log4J vulnerability that can create "uncontrolled recursion from self-referential lookups" (CVE-2021-45105).

Official Apache security node (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) mentions that if you cannot upgrade Log4j library to 2.17.0, then one of the mitigation is following -

"In PatternLayout in the logging configuration, replace Context Lookups like ${ctx:loginId} or $${ctx:loginId} with Thread Context Map patterns (%X, %mdc, or %MDC)"

Can someone please confirm that all this means is following - >

Replace $${ctx:loginId} pattern with %X{loginId} patten and this will mitigate the risk?

Regards

Comment: But seriously ... if you can't upgrade to 2.17.0, that probably also means that you can't upgrade to 2.16.0 ... and that one (CVE-2021-45046) is 1) potentially more dangerous (depending on what you are putting into the logs), and 2) not possible to mitigate.

Comment: In short ... you shouldn't be looking for ways to mitigate.  At this point you should prioritize upgrading.  Especially if it is just a matter of replacing the vulnerable JAR files.

Comment: To mitigate risk of (CVE-2021-45046), we have removed Jndilook.class from JAR file. The reason I cannot upgrade is that Log4J JAR is coming as part of a packaged software and other libraries in package has dependencies on it. We need to wait for official patch from Vendor.